# Rails, order collection through double-layered association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A character `has_many :conversations through: chats`, and each conversation `has_many :messages`. When I call `@character.conversations`, I want the conversations to be ordered by the time of creation of the latest message belonging to the conversation. How is this coded?

**character.rb**

```
has_many :chats, foreign_key: "character_id",
has_many :conversations, through: :chats, source: :conversation
# order: "conversation.messages.last.created_at DESC" # doesn't work
```

**conversation.rb**

```
has_many :chats, foreign_key: "conversation_id"
has_many :characters, through: :chats, source: :character
has_many :messages
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `default_scope` to **conversation.rb**:

```
default_scope -> {includes(:messages).order('messages.created_at DESC')}
```

**Note:** *`default_scope` would certainly hamper the performance since the query will run all the time when you access any conversation. A better approach would be to create a separate scope which you can call when needed.*

Comment: I've added the default_scope you suggested to **conversation.rb**, but it doesn't seem to affect the order of conversations, rather it is ordering the messages within each conversation. I'd like it to order the conversations themselves?

Comment: @Bazley can you just do `@character.conversations` and post the generated **SQL** ?   You can try this out in your console and see the `ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply additional scopes to the relation, even when it's multi-layered:

```
@character.conversations.joins(:messages).order('messages.created_at DESC')
```